# Why to use NotImplementedError when method overriding can solve the same purpose in below two programs?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

### I have created class Animal  and **method overriding** is used to get the separate sound of 2 different animals:

```
class Animal: 

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name    
    def sound(self):
        return 'animal sound'

class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self,name, breed):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.breed=breed
    def sound(self):
        return f"dog: woof woof"    

class Cat(Animal):

    def __init__(self,name,breed):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.breed=breed
    def sound(self):
        return f" cat: meow meow"

doggy=Dog('boony','Pug')
kitten=Cat('suzi', 'Siamese')
print(doggy.sound())
print(kitten.sound())
```

---

Next, same program with **NotImplementedError** is used to not to get any error while getting separate sounds of 2 different animals.

---

```
class Animal: 

    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name    
    def sound(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("You have to define this method in subclass")

class Dog(Animal):

    def __init__(self,name, breed):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.breed=breed

    def sound(self):
        return 'dog: woof woof'        

class Cat(Animal):

    def __init__(self,name,breed):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.breed=breed
    def sound(self):
        return 'cat: meow meow'

doggy=Dog('boony','Pug')
kitten=Cat('suzi', 'Siamese')
print(doggy.sound())
print(kitten.sound())
```